# JS Change class of element

Tags: javascript

All I'm trying to do is toggle the class of an elements by ID when they are clicked on.

```
<script>

function selectLoad(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).className == "load") {
        document.getElementById(id).className = "loadSelected";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).className = "load";
    }
}

</script>

<div class="load" id=" ... set by PHP per element ... " onclick="selectLoad(this)">
```

This returns an error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null

So I guess it doesn't like the conditional.

I'm new to JS and need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: `document.getElementById(id)` is returning null.  Make sure you're passing in the correct id to `setLoad`

Comment: Also, save the return value of getElementsById in a var, you use a lot useless time searching the dom for one element

Comment: I guess that ´"selectLoad(this)"´ might trouble you. More easy setting with php the id: ´"selectLoad(\''.php_var.'\');"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the dom element itself (using `this`), not the `id`.

You should change the code to

```
function selectLoad(element)
{
    if (element.className == "load") {
        element.className = "loadSelected";
    } else {
        element.className = "load";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are passing an id that does not exist in the dom. Has the dom loaded before your javascript is executed? Move the script to the bottom of the page just before the closing html tag

EDIT: Following discussion in comments below the error is this line:

```
<div class="load" id=" ... set by PHP per element ... " onclick="selectLoad(this)">
```

it should read

```
<div class="load" id=" ... set by PHP per element ... " onclick="selectLoad(this.id)">
```

Comment: OP's not passing an ID at all. The call is passing in a DOM element.

Comment: yes he is. In selectElementById(id), id is an id! The problem is that the id is not one that exists on an element in the dom

Comment: "Has the dom loaded before your javascript is executed?" if you'd read the HTML, you'd know the script was being used as an `onclick` callback, which means the DOM has definitely loaded.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `document.getElementById`, I was referring to where OP is calling `selectLoad(this)` which is passing a DOM element as a parameter, as `this` refers to the `div`.

Comment: you should use `this.id` rather than `this.getAttribute('id')`, as it's much more concise.

Comment: @zzzzBov - agreed. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not safe because you don't check if you have the DOM element with the given `id`

That is why you get the error: `Cannot read property 'className' of null`

```
if(document.getElementById(id)) {
    // ... do something and do not go further.
    return;
}
```

And the problem is passing `this` when you call `selectLoad`. At this point, `this` is the DOM element, not the string that yo expect: `... set by PHP per element ...`. So you have to change the code accordingly.